# Resize text when zooming/dezooming in D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I am currently internship at the "Direction Générale de l'Armement" and I need to do something.

I have a "network" type of d3.js code, I added the zoom/dezoom function, but I want to resize the text when we are zooming/dezooming.
When it zoom on a node, I want the text to lower a bit, and more important, when we dezoom I want the text to get bigger.
As we can find it on the internet, the zoom function that i added was this one :

```
      var svg = d3.select("p")
  .append("svg")

     .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom",function(){svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
     }))

  .append("g");
```

Do you have an idea ? Thanks a lot !

[(Here is a picture of it)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAS3e.png)

Comment: Not exactly sure, what you are after. Are you looking for [semantic zooming](https://observablehq.com/@john-guerra/svg-semantic-zoom)?